# How to record a JNLP/ Java Web Start application with JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, java-web-start, jnlp, ubikloadpack

I need to do a performance test for JNLP accessible application.

I used WireShark and see that the jnlp generates only TCP traffic.

I read all the post related with jnlp perf testing and I tried with [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) + [UbikLoadPack](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/load-testing-java-serialization-applications-with-jmeter/) Java Serialization plugin but jmeter does not capture the traffic.

Is it my only option capture the TCP traffic and work with that ?

Regards,
Jaime

Comment: JNLP isn't a protocol like TCP. It s really nothing more than the format of a file. All the traffic is conducted over HTTP or FTP or whatever you define for the URLs in the JNLP file. Hard to see why you would be concerned about performance. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If traffic is HTTP(s), as per documentation of UbikLoadPack bundle, You need to follow the instructions of paragraphs:

**1/Add JMeter certificate authority to the cacerts file used by Java:**

See in documentation "*Configuring Application for HTTPS*" (Pages 7/8). This will allow your application to work when using JMeter as proxy if traffic is HTTPS

Steps are the following:

- Start JMeter
- Use File > Templates... Menu item, then select "Recording" Template and click Create
  [image: Recording Template]
- Start HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder by clicking on Start Button
  [image: Start Recording]
- JMeter will generate a Certificate Authority in 2 formats in jmeter/bin folder:

  - ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt
  - ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.usr
- Find cacerts file used by your system, it should be in JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
- Run:

> keytool -keystore cacerts -importcert -alias jmeter_ca -file <path to jmeter>/bin/ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt

- keystore password is usually "changeit"
- enter "yes" for "Trust this certificate?" question

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java-add-certificate-ca-store
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11937940/460802
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8980460/460802

**2/To set JMeter as proxy of JNLP:**

- Open the Java Control Panel

[image: Java Control Panel]

- Click Network Settings. The Network Settings dialog box opens.
- Select Use proxy server, enter the proxy server name (localhost), and port number (8888 for JMeter).

[image: Proxy Configuration]

- Click Advanced and check "Use same proxy server for all protocols":

[image: Use same proxy for all protocols]
- Click Apply
- Restart your application again

See reference documentation:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/networking/proxie_config.html
- [Force java web start to use a proxy like Fiddler without touching code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842412/force-java-web-start-to-use-a-proxy-like-fiddler-without-touching-code)

If it’s not HTTP, the plugin does not support it.